# $\phi$ function is multiplicative (abstract proof)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

We want to proove that Euler's $\phi$ function is multiplicative. 
We have to show that $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, $ if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$.

We know that $\phi (n):=|U(\mathbb{Z}_n)|$. 
Also, $ \mathbb{Z}_{nm} \cong \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m, \forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z^+} $ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$. (isomorphic rings)

So in these two isomorphic rings the no zero unit elements in  $\mathbb{Z}_{nm}$, will be the "same" in $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m $. So, $|U(\mathbb{Z}_{nm})| = |U(\mathbb{Z}_n)|| U( \mathbb{Z}_m) | \implies \phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n) $. Is this right?

Furthermore, can we say that $U(\mathbb{Z}_{nm}) \cong U(\mathbb{Z}_n) \times U(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ (multiplicative groups)? And can we prove it finding a bijection without Chinese remainder theorem?

*(I know that this question already exists but the answer I am looking for is different and abstract).*

Thank you

Comment: The notation for the multiplicative group is $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$

Comment: To do this abstractly, show that if $R$ and $S$ are rings then $U(R\times S)=U(R)\times U(S)$.

Comment: @m_t_ I think that we have to proove at first that $(R, +, \cdot ) \cong (R_1 \times R_2, +, \cdot)  \implies (U(R), \cdot ) \cong (U(R_1 \times R_2), \cdot) = (U(R_1) \times U(R_2),  \cdot)$. But how?

Comment: An isomorphism maps units to units, so if $\Lambda \cong \Gamma$ then $U(\Lambda)\cong U(\Gamma)$. To show $U(R\times S)=U(R)\times U(S)$, try to do $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$

Comment: @m_t_ $U(R_1 \times R_2)=U(R_1) \times U(R_2)$ because;
 
 If $(a,b) \in U(R_1 \times R_2) \implies \exists (c,d) \in (R_1\times R_2) -(\{0,0\}) : (a,b)(c,d)=(1,1) \implies (ac,bd)=(1,1) \implies ac=1 \ bd=1 \implies (a,b)\in U(R_1) \times (R_2)$. So we have $\subseteq$. Working similarly, we will have $\supseteq $. But, could you explain me why if $\Lambda \cong \Gamma \implies U(\Lambda)\cong U(\Gamma)$? Thank you for your time!

Comment: If the iso is f, show f(unit)=unit. Then you know f induces an injection of unit groups. But the same argument implies the inverse of f preserves the unit groups. So f restricted to U(R) is an iso because it has inverse $f^{-1}$ restricted to U(S)

Comment: @m_t_ Can we find a different proof? For example to find a bijection such that $φ: U(R) \longrightarrow U(S)$ is an group isomorphism?

Comment: The bijection you can find is the one I described: f restricted to the unit group.